# Oracle sql - greather than from calculated amounts

Tags: sql, oracle

I received this script to execute:

```
SELECT b.tablespace_name,
       tbs_size SizeMb,
       a.free_space FreeMb,
       CAST(round(((tbs_size - a.free_space)/tbs_size)*100,2)AS VARCHAR(6)) || '%'
         PercentFull
FROM   (
         SELECT tablespace_name,
                round(SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 ,2) AS free_space
          FROM   dba_free_space
          GROUP BY tablespace_name
        ) a,
        (
          SELECT tablespace_name,
                 SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 AS tbs_size
          FROM   dba_data_files
          GROUP BY tablespace_name
          UNION
          SELECT tablespace_name,
                 SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 tbs_size
          FROM   dba_temp_files
          GROUP BY tablespace_name
        ) b
WHERE a.tablespace_name(+)=b.tablespace_name;
```

[scores without zero before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7LXM.png)

First problem was with '0' between score, I changed it for:

```
SELECT b.tablespace_name,
       tbs_size SizeMb,
       a.free_space FreeMb,
       TO_CHAR(round(((tbs_size - a.free_space)/tbs_size)*100,2),'00.99' ) || '%'
         PercentFull
FROM   (
         SELECT tablespace_name,
                round(SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 ,2) AS free_space
         FROM dba_free_space
         GROUP BY tablespace_name
       ) a,
       (
         SELECT tablespace_name,
                SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 AS tbs_size
         FROM   dba_data_files
         GROUP BY tablespace_name
         UNION
         SELECT tablespace_name,
                SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 tbs_size
         FROM   dba_temp_files
         GROUP BY tablespace_name
       ) b
WHERE a.tablespace_name(+)=b.tablespace_name;
```

[scores with lost zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45oGp.png)

Now I have lost zeros, but I still cannot find solution, how to show scores greater than 50%. - Can you help me?

Comment: Please post text instead of pictures. Stackoverflowers will be happier

Comment: ok, sorry for that, I'm new here and try to learn how to post best

Comment: so you just want the rows with scores greater than 50%? right?

Comment: yes, greater than 50%, I tried with HAVING etc, but get only errors

Comment: yes, HAVING is the solution. i added an answer. should work. just let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to receive rows, where the percentage is greater than 50%, you could just add this restriction to `WHERE`-clause like:

```
SELECT b.tablespace_name,
       tbs_size SizeMb,
       a.free_space FreeMb,
       CAST(round(((tbs_size - a.free_space)/tbs_size)*100,2)AS VARCHAR(6)) || '%'
         PercentFull
FROM   (
         SELECT tablespace_name,
                round(SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 ,2) AS free_space
          FROM   dba_free_space
          GROUP BY tablespace_name
        ) a,
        (
          SELECT tablespace_name,
                 SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 AS tbs_size
          FROM   dba_data_files
          GROUP BY tablespace_name
          UNION
          SELECT tablespace_name,
                 SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 tbs_size
          FROM   dba_temp_files
          GROUP BY tablespace_name
        ) b
WHERE a.tablespace_name(+)=b.tablespace_name;
 AND round(((tbs_size - a.free_space)/tbs_size)*100,2) > 50
```

Comment: I have an error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 45 Column: 11

Comment: @mehow my fault. i changed the answer. its a  simple condition in the where clause

Comment: now I have error: Error starting at line : 58 in command -
 AND round(((tbs_size - a.free_space)/tbs_size)*100,2) > 50
Error report -
Unknown Command

Comment: I added: WHERE a.tablespace_name(+)=b.tablespace_name and (((tbs_size - a.free_space)/tbs_size)*100)>50; and it's working. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
SELECT b.tablespace_name, 
       tbs_size SizeMb, 
       a.free_space FreeMb, 
       TO_CHAR(round(((tbs_size - a.free_space)/tbs_size)*100,2),'00.99' ) || '%' 
       PercentFull 
FROM (
       SELECT tablespace_name, 
              round(SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 ,2) AS free_space 
              FROM dba_free_space 
              GROUP BY tablespace_name
      ) a, 
      (
       SELECT tablespace_name, 
              SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 AS tbs_size 
              FROM dba_data_files 
              GROUP BY tablespace_name 
              UNION 
              SELECT tablespace_name, 
                     SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 tbs_size 
              FROM dba_temp_files 
              GROUP BY tablespace_name 
      ) b 
WHERE a.tablespace_name(+)=b.tablespace_name 
      and (((tbs_size - a.free_space)/tbs_size)*100)>50;
```